# Heroku specify which app to run command on?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

In my git repo I have added two different heroku remotes to separate apps (named testheroku and officialheroku).

I am able to push to them separately by specifying their remote name (i.e. `git push officialheroku master`) but when try to use `heroku run python manage.py syncdb` it only runs syncdb for testheroku.

How do I make heroku run syncdb on officialheroku?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli):

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdb --app officialheroku
```

As an FYI, the general usage syntax from the CLI is as follows:

```
heroku COMMAND [--app APP] [command-specific-options]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this:

- `heroku --app heroku_app_name` (where the app name is the *foo* part in `foo.herokuapp.com`)
- `heroku --remote git_remote_name` (where the remote name is one of the items that shows up in the list when you run `git remote`)

Comment: @AswinKumar You still need the Heroku command, e.g. `heroku --app heroku_app_name run python manage.py syncdb`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the git remote names you've defined in the CLI you pass it explicitly using the -r parameter

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdb -r testheroku|officialheroku
```